# Power BI - Merging Using a Reference Table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Can you merge queries in Power Bi Query Editor if table 1 (The table on top) is a reference? When I try to do so, all I see is "No Preview is Available".

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I'm using a rather large file and it was taking forever to finish working with all of the data. Until it's finished, I can't do another step, which in this case, is merge.